# Not able to track lead sources from campaign links in react native

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, event-tracking, react-android

I am using this npm for analytics events. All the events are tracking as expected.
My issue is with respect to capturing the lead source. Most of the sources are coming as (direct) or (not set).

I have used the following code snippet inside manifest to receive the broadcasts sources.

```
   <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

When I test this as specified by this link : [Link to test if its working before taking the app to live](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#prepare.)

I am getting the below logcat:

> 05-21 18:49:35.975 8806 9318 W GAv4 : CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible.

Should I be using react-native-google-analytics-bridge to track all the sources or is there a way to track the sources within react-native-firebase itself?

Comment: Have you got any solution on this?